# Fallback in html 5 application cache not working

Tags: html, fallback, application-cache

My appcache is given below and it works perfectly. It works great when i am offline and visit nocache.html page where it shows me offline.html page. Below is the working example -

```
CACHE MANIFEST
cache.html

NETWORK:
nocache.html

FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

Now i want to ask that when i change the fallback to -

```
FALLBACK:
nocache.html offline.html
```

then it does not work. Can somebody tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "it does not work"? What do you do to test, what do you expect to happen, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: I use VS 2013, i stop IIS then open nocache.html in the browser. It redirect me to offline.html page. Works well in the first case but in the second case when i write FALLBACK:nocache.html offline.html i do not see this instead i get 'could not connect'

Answer (score 0):

If you change your network section entry to the more typical `*`, it works the way you expect.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
cache.html

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
nocache.html offline.html
```

It's possible that by explicitly identifying `nocache.html` in the `NETWORK` section, the browser will not permit a `FALLBACK` for it.

I do not know if that is spec-compliant or not and I'm merely guessing, so comments or edits from more knowledgable people are welcome.

Comment: i tested your code it works putting * in network.  I think that putting page name in both network and fallback is causing the problem.